# BaseFilter, SerializedTextFilter and more are missing after upgrade from ag-grid 18.1.2 to ag-grid-community 20.1.0

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

After upgrading from ag-grid 18.1.2 to ag-grid 20.1.0 (ag-grid-community), it is no longer possible to import BaseFilter, SerializedTextFilter, SerializedDateFilter, and SerializedNumberFilter.

I can see them in the git source code under dist/lib/filter (https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/tree/master/dist/lib/filter) but they are not available in the code under node_modules/ag-grid-community after installation.

My app contains classes that extends BaseFilter, and it's using all of the mentioned interfaces. I have searched for answers online without luck.

The following works with ag-grid@18.1.2 but not with ag-grid-community@21.1.0. BaseFilter and SerializedTextFilter are not available to import

```
import { BaseFilter, IFilterParams, SerializedTextFilter } from 'ag-grid';

class CustomFilterComponent<P extends IFilterParams, M extends SerializedTextFilter>
    extends BaseFilter<string, P, M> {

    customInit(): void {
        ...
    }   

    isFilterActive(): boolean {
        ...
    }

    ....
}
```

I expected there to be information regarding these changes to the ag-grid library, and how to deal with it. I have not been able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by not extending BaseFilter, and using TextFilterModel, DateFilterModel, and NumberFilterModel instead of SerializedTextFilter, SerializedDateFilter, and SerializedNumberFilter, and using constants from SimpleFilter instead of BaseFilter.